# Is there any way to plot a 1 variable function in 3d plot?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

all, I'm trying to plot a 2d function with only 1 variable in 3d coordinate: y=9x-x^3....It should be just 1 curved line on xy-plane......Is there anyway to do it??? Don't ask me why, too much to explain.....Below are the codes I have so far, it works, but the direction is wrong which I don't understand why, it should curve on xy-plane, not xz-plane......Then I don't really understand how 3dplot, pgfplot anyway....so help! Oh, and my package name might be wrong, if the code doesn't compile, check the package name.....Apology for the inconvenience, I typed the package on site, might spelled some wrong......Thanks!

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplot}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[domain=0:2.00,
samples=20,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3 [domain = 0:3] {9*x-x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicutre}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of something like,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$z$,
                zlabel=$y$,
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20}]
\addplot3[surf, samples=50, domain=0:2] ({x},{y},{9*x - x^3});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But there is possibly a better way to parametrize it. In the code below, the variable y plays the role of the variable z, so you can fine tune the domain of x and z. Also the point of view can be adjusted by changing the values of the two angles (polar and azimuthal angles).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                xmin=0,
                xmax=2,
                ticks=none,
                view={40}{50}]
\addplot3[surf, samples=50, domain=0:2, y domain=0:2] ({x},{9*x - x^3},{y});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Romain

Answer (score 2):

I was reading the question a bit differently, namely as the request for a curve in the x-y-plane. Here are two ways to accomplish that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{40}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
\draw plot[domain=0:3,samples=100,variable=\x] ({\x},{9*\x*(1-\x*\x/9)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[domain=0:2.00,
samples=50,samples y=1
]
\addplot3 [domain = 0:3] ({x},{9*x-x*x*x},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the viewing angles are different in these plots.

Comment: You may need to specify `samples y=1`, otherwise it will still sample a mesh.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thanks a lot! (I really love the packages you wrote!)